# Mover directorios recursivamente en windows o DOS

Tags: windows, .bat

Tenemos una estructura de directorios del tipo, unos dentro de otros

```
dir 1
  - dir A
  - dir B
dir 2
  - dir C
dir 3
dir 4
```

Y me gustaria moverlos todos a otro directorio, todos al mismo nivel, es decir

```
dir 1
dir A
dir B
dir 2
```

He probado el siguiente código pero no funciona

```
 for %%x in (%*) do (
    move %%x d:\resul\
)
```

Con un script en .bat, o linea de comando

Comment: mirate sin codigó y sin saber que lenguaje usas no se te puede ayudar mucho. Pero mirate la documentación de microsoft en el siguiente link si lo haces en C#
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-6.0

Comment: Seria en linea de comando, bat. Edito pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución seria ..

```
@echo off
cd D:\data\folder
call :treeProcess
goto :eof

:treeProcess
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   cd "%%d"
   call :treeProcess
   cd ..
   move "%%d" D:\basedir
)
exit /b
```